# Windows Server DNS UDP

Tags: windows, dns, udp

If you have DNS issues UDP port 53 first check your ISP is not blocking/filtering it. I have had issues with OVH dedicated servers. I had 3 servers with them and on 2 of them they seem to have filtered UDP port 53. But strangely enough some requests were going through. I don't know what sort of filtering they are using it just took sometime for me to figure out this issue and get in touch with them to resolve it. Apart from that they are a great hosting provider.

Comment: You’ve really shown up and presented us a black box, then proceeded to ask us what is wrong with what’s inside the black box. This question, as it is presented, is absolutely unable to be answered. Please provide the necessary details to actually solve the issue. Exact error messages, exact details about your DNS servers, how they are hosted, how they are connected to the internet, how your domains are registered, how you’ve configured NS servers, and really, if you actually want an answer you’ll need to provide the domain name having trouble so we can just check for ourselves.

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details.

Comment: Perfect. I can already see there are some issues. But, I'm not particularly sure what they are yet. I'm looking in to it.

Comment: https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3abissano.com&run=toolpage#
here I select DNS Check and it always shows just NS2 live but it doesn't say exactly what is wrong with the others. Linux DIG for NS records works for all 3 of them every time.

Answer (score 0):

The 3 DNS servers listed are:
`ns1.bissano.com`
`ns2.bissano.com` and
`ns3.bissano.com`.

I've checked the domain registration records for `bissano.com` including the glue records necessary for hosting your own custom nameservers that are part of the same domain. Everything on the registration side looks fine.

However, neither `ns1.bissano.com` nor `ns3.bissano.com` are responding to any DNS requests I throw at it.

The IP addresses for these 2 servers are: `139.99.144.21` and `164.132.206.117`

A quick online port check to both of these servers shows that port 53 (DNS) is OPEN. But, when sent a query for `bissano.com` both time out. You can see those results by using the tool here: http://www.webdnstools.com/dnstools/domain_check

The servers specified for ns1 and ns3 are NOT responding to our DNS requests. That is your problem, but I cannot tell you why that is. You'll have to double-check the configuration on those servers. If you have access to those servers, you should start at the source. Login to it, see if you can query it locally with a command like `nslookup bissano.com. 127.0.0.1`. Go from there and make sure that firewalls/port forwards are setup properly. Make sure the servers are configured to except external requests. Insure that the DNS zones themselves are configured correctly.

Comment: :) This is what I stated in the question. I used nslookup and it is resolving. I also tried DIG from linux e.g. this  dig NS bissano.com 139.99.144.21 or this  dig NS bissano.com 164.132.206.117 always works everytime. I don't know what else they run on these online checkers so it fails.

Comment: @BisserMilanov I understand that. I confirmed it for you. I can’t see inside those servers, their hosting providers, or their firewall rules. You’ll have to focus on why those servers aren’t responding. I gave some high level suggestions. I suggest focusing on the two problematic servers and then posting new questions about what you find, if you still have questions.

Comment: I will post whatever I find.

Answer (score 0):

OK finally found the solution. It was due to some sort of gaming protection installed on the side of the hosting provider. As soon as I disabled it I had no issues of any kind. Before that it would mostly not work but surprisingly it would sometimes work. So if anyone else is hosting with OVH check their firewalls and disabled them before you do anything else.